# Error while trying to access class attributes

Tags: delphi, attributes, rtti

I have this class:

```
{$RTTI EXPLICIT FIELDS([vcProtected]) PROPERTIES([vcProtected])}
const
  PP_VEHICLE_FIELD = 'VEICULO_ID';
  PP_DRIVER_FIELD = 'MOTORISTA_ID';
  PP_TRIP_FIELD = 'VIAGEM_ID';
  PP_DATE = 'DATA';

type
  [TAttrDBTable('NONE')]
  TReportItem = class(TObject)
  protected
    [TAttrDBField(PP_VEHICLE_FIELD)]
    FVeiculoId: integer;
    [TAttrDBField(PP_DRIVER_FIELD)]
    FMotoristaId: integer;
    [TAttrDBField(PP_TRIP_FIELD)]
    FViagemId: integer;
    [TAttrDBField(PP_DATE)]
    FDataRelatorio: TDate;
  published
    class function GetTableName<T: class, constructor>: string;
  end.

class function TReportItem.GetTableName<T>: string;
var
  LRttiContext: TRttiContext;
  LRttiType: TRttiType;
  LCustomAttribute: TCustomAttribute;
  LType: T;
begin
  LType := T.Create;
  try
    LRttiContext := TRttiContext.Create;
    LRttiType := LRttiContext.GetType(LType.ClassType);
    for LCustomAttribute in LRttiType.GetAttributes do
      if LCustomAttribute is TAttrDBTable then
      begin
        Result := TAttrDBTable(LCustomAttribute).TableName;
        Break;
      end;
  finally
    LType.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I call it this way: `TReportItem.GetTableName<TReportItem>`; The `<>` can be any class that inherit `TReportItem`.

But, sometimes when I call: `TReportItem.GetTableName` in the command `LRttiType.GetAttributes` I get an access violation, sometimes not, depends of the 'compilation'. It works and stop working like magic.
I don't know what is happening. Someone can give me a hint ?

The problem is on the `GetAttributes`, if I use that to get attributes in fiels, methods etc. It give me access violation. Is there some directive that I must to turn on or off to use it?

If I compile using <kbd>Shift+F9</kbd>, the `GetAttributes` give me AV, if I modify any line in the unit and compile using <kbd>F9</kbd> `GetAttributes` works.

It's not only in my machine, other 8 programmers are with the same problem. Delphi XE.

The error occurs in this code in *rtti.pas*:

```
function FindCtor(AttrType: TRttiInstanceType; CtorAddr: Pointer): TRttiMethod;
type
  PPPointer = ^PPointer;
var
  p: PByte;
  imp: Pointer;
begin
  for Result in AttrType.GetMethods do
    if Result.CodeAddress = CtorAddr then
      Exit;
  // expect a package (i.e. DLL) import
  p := CtorAddr;
  Assert(p^ = $FF); // $FF $25 => indirect jump m32
  Inc(p);
  Assert(p^ = $25);
  Inc(p);
  imp := PPPointer(p)^^; //ERROR HAPPENS HERE
  for Result in attrType.GetMethods do
    if Result.CodeAddress = imp then
      Exit;
  Result := nil;
end;
```

Comment: Can you show your call to `TReportItem.GetTableName`.

Comment: When you get the AV, what value does `LRttiType` have?

Comment: @SaCi you wrote, you get AV when trying to get attributes for fields and properties but in code above `getAttributes` is used only to get class attributes. (if your fields and props are public, then  seems to me, you have to inlclude vcPublic in `$RTTI` directive too)

Comment: Yes, I'm debugging, in LRttiType I can access everything I want, fields (GetFields), methods(GetMethods) etc, but when I try to access the attributes it give me an av.

Comment: I solved the problem, but I didn't found the reason.
I moved the unit to the begin in dpr and it works. So, some unit compilation should be causing the error. And for some reason the directives that I used didn't solve the problem.
I'll try to find the true reason and post here.

Comment: By the way, your function doesn't need generics. If `T` is supposed to be a class that descends from `TReportItem`, then just call `T.GetTableName`. Within the function, replace `T` with `Self`. You can also replace `LType.ClassType` with `Self`. Declare `LType` as `TReportItem`.

Comment: @SaCi, I have the same problem and I tried to move the unit as you, but the error persist, did you figure out what can cause this?

Comment: Yes Cesar, I did! Was a coding "error", make sure you have M+ directive on, and choose yours rtti directives correctly. If you need some extra help, e-mail me. Regards

Comment: @SaCi the classes already have $M+, all this classes are specialized from TPersistent and to my classes I added: {$RTTI EXPLICIT PROPERTIES([vcPublic, vcPublished])}.

Comment: @CesarRomero e-mail me, rodrigofrezino@gmail.com, send the code or what you can. I can try help no problem

Comment: @SaCi, thank you for you offer, it seems to be a RTTI bug indeed, check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201817/enable-delphi-xe-rtti-only-for-some-classes and the related QC http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=98261, and if you agree, could add some votes to bring more attention to the QC.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem for hours today, same AV on `imp := PPPointer(p)^^` in Rtti.pas.

I discovered that I used the same name for 2 attributes in 2 unrelated units in my project: after I renamed one of them, no more AV!

Comment: I have the same problem and do not have attributes with same name I have also changed the unit inside the .dpr as @SaCi, but the error persists